# How to implement Parcelable interface to interface?

Tags: java, android

Below is the sample code for making implement Parcelable of a class "MyParcelable" according to Android Developer Documentation.

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };

 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
  }
 }
```

But What if it is an Interface? And suppose it has only one method definition then what would be the code for it? For e.g.

```
public interface MyParcelable extends Parcelable {

void parcelable();

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to archieve. You do not "implement" inside interfaces. By extending the `Parcelable` interface you create a new interface that can be implemented by classes. In your case a class that implements `MyParcelable` would have to implement all the methods from the `Parcelable` interface and your `parcelable()`method.

Comment: okay. I had already tried that but after that and I got android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Student implements Parcelable {

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Student(in);
        }

        public Student[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Student[size];
        }
    };

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String grade;

    // Constructor
    public Student(long id, String name, String grade){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    // Parcelling part
       public Student(Parcel in){
           this.id = in.readLong();
           this.name = in.readString();
           this.grade =  in.readString();
       }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
       public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.grade);
       }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", grade='" + grade + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am Asking about interface that would extends Parcelable.

Comment: You can Implement Interface another Interface